# Take existing project and move it into a Ruby on Rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, web-applications

I have the front end of a website built.  It is made from a number of HTML, JavaScript, and Jquery files.  Is there a way to take those files and move them into a Ruby on Rails environment so that I don't need to remake everything?

Comment: It really depends on the context of the site. What was it meant to do? Did it serve static files, or did it provide users with dynamic, interactive content? What exactly is your motivation here for attempting this?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Create a new rails app (`rails new app-name`). Copy your existing javascript files into the Rails project at `public/javascripts/`. Your views/html are a bit more dependent on how you want to grow.

One option is to create a single `PagesController` and not bother with resources/models/etc, and you would just put all of your "views" into `/app/views/pages/`. You don't even have to rename them to `.html.erb` like you would conventionally see — you can leave them as just plain html. Your routes.rb file would look something like this:

```
get '/:action', :controller => 'pages', :as => 'page'
```

Which would afford you routes like "example.com/hello_world" that would route to PagesController#hello_world, rendering "app/views/pages/hello_world.html". If you want to use ERb, you can add that ".erb" suffix to your view file and then you can use the `page_path` helper to assemble links:

```
<%= link_to 'Hello World Demo', page_path('hello_world') %>
```

You will still probably want to extract the common elements into a layout at `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` (again, the ERb being optional).

---

Another route would be to actually separate your application into *resources*. If you have a page that lists books, for example, you could create a BooksController and put the relevant view under `app/views/books/index.html`. This doesn't make sense to do if you're not going to provide some additional functionality in the future, though.